# A Simulation to Disable Page Elements and Display UpdateProgress Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, ajax

Am trying to disable page elements & display update progress control in my application. To make it work, I have applied style sheet with the property

filter:alpha(opacity=85);

but its showing an error "filter is not a known CSS property name".
Can anyone suggest me what can be done for this?

Also give me an idea of disabling page elements when displaying update progress control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter is IE specific, use Opacity for other browsers.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Comment: If you find it helpful could you mark it as an answer ;) Or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <!--[if IE ]>
    .youeElemet{
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)"; // first!
        filter: alpha(opacity=85);
    }
    <![endif]-->
```